# Vibration won't stop

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

When I "stop - finish" the game scene, if a vibration is occurring, it does not stop. And I can't figure it why.

When the player collide with left or right barrier, the phone make a vibration. But if I close the game, while is vibrating, it will keep vibrating untile the the controller is deinitialised.
Why?

I even try to reposition the player, but still it vibrates.

**Close functions**

**View controller**

```
func closeGame() {
    if isUserNeedAuthenticating {
        Vibrations.longVibrate()
        viewModel.uploadPoints()
        scene?.stopGame()
        showNextController()
}
```

**Game Scene**

```
func stopGame() {
    gameTimer?.invalidate()
    stopObjectTimers()
    stopMotionManager()
    self.removeAllActions()
    self.removeAllChildren()
}
```

**Vibrate functions**

```
func playerDidCollideWithLeftBarrier() {
    Vibrations.longVibrate()
    let spark = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Sparkling")!
    spark.setScale(0.3)
    player.addChild(spark)
    spark.position = CGPoint(x: -(player.size.width/4), y: 0)
    self.run(SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.2)) {
        spark.removeFromParent()
    }
}

func playerDidCollideWithRightBarrier() {
    Vibrations.longVibrate()
    let spark = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Sparkling")!
    spark.setScale(0.3)
    player.addChild(spark)
    spark.position = CGPoint(x: (player.size.width/4), y: 0)
    self.run(SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.2)) {
        spark.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

**movment function**

```
override func didSimulatePhysics() {
        let mirrorWidth: CGFloat = 15
        let min = (player.size.width / 2) + mirrorWidth
        let max = frame.width - (player.size.width / 2) - mirrorWidth
        let newPosition = player.position.x + xAcceleration * 30
        if (newPosition < min) {
            playerDidCollideWithLeftBarrier()
            player.position.x = min
            return
        } else if (newPosition > max) {
            player.position.x = max
            playerDidCollideWithRightBarrier()
            return
        } else {
            player.position.x = newPosition
        }
    }


/// A class used to play vibrations
final class Vibrations {

    /// Play a short single vibration, like a tac
    static func tacVibrate() {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1519) // one tack
    }

    /// Play three shorts tac vibration, like a tac tac tac
    static func threeTacVibrate() {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1521)
    }

    /// Play a strong boom vibration
    static func boomVibrate() {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1520)
    }

    /// Play a long vibrations trr trr, it sounds like an error
    static func longVibrate() {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate) // heavy tack
    }
}
```

Comment: because the signal isn't being sent to end the vibration.  There are NSNotifications being sent when your app is about to close,   use those notifications to ensure your game enters into a suspended state.  BTW, timers will mess up your game in Sprite Kit, so i would recommend avoiding them.

Comment: thank you for your tipe, but the game is very small and timers are good for what I'm doing. Anyway, can you be more specific about the notification? maybe some code?

Comment: Doesnt matter how small the game is,  Sprite Kit relies on its own timing system. simply getting a call in the middle of your game is going to cause your game to do undesired things.  As for notifications, there are a plethora of examples on SO,  just search swift appdelegate notification to get started.

Comment: I mean, witch notification should I trigger to stop the vibration?

Comment: you don't trigger a notification to stop it, you use one of the notification to go through your scene to ensure that whatever is retaining the vibration no longer exists.

Comment: that's the problem, I can't figure it how the vibration persist, so I don't know rich is the object

Comment: whatever "Vibrations" is

Comment: /// Play a long vibrations trr trr, it sounds like an error
    static func longVibrate() {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate) // heavy tack
    }

Comment: I would recommend switching to `UIFeedbackGenerator`

Answer (score 1):

In your appdelegate, during the will resign notification, add the following line:

```
AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
```

You should also add it for any other ID you need cancelled.

You can also add it to your class to make it easier.

```
final class Vibrations {

    /// Play a short single vibration, like a tac
    static func tacVibrate() {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1519) // one tack
    }

    /// Play three shorts tac vibration, like a tac tac tac
    static func threeTacVibrate() {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1521)
    }

    /// Play a strong boom vibration
    static func boomVibrate() {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1520)
    }

    /// Play a long vibrations trr trr, it sounds like an error
    static func longVibrate() {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate) // heavy tack
    }

    /// Stops the short single vibration, like a tac
    static func stopTacVibrate() {
        AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(1519) // one tack
    }

    /// Stops the three shorts tac vibration, like a tac tac tac
    static func stopThreeTacVibrate() {
        AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(1521)
    }

    /// Stops the strong boom vibration
    static func stopBoomVibrate() {
        AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(1520)
    }

    /// Stops the long vibrations 
    static func stopLongVibrate() {
        AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate) // heavy tack
    }

}
```

Comment: call it immediately after play, and let me know if that stops the vibration?

Comment: nop :(. I think the problem is the segues or something relative to the close function. Because, when I move the car off the barriers, it stops to vibrate... Just when I close the game when the car is colliding to the barrier

Comment: I will have to play with it,  Dispose sound is suppose to stop it